# I am sending Envelopes through python using Docusing SDK/API, but can not see in the application

Tags: docusignapi

I Have created one python based application which integrates Docusign SDk/API, I am able to send envelopes to users email but when i am login to docusing account which i have integrated it is not showing anything on home page cards. where i can track that.

I did not found any solution.

Comment: I would recommend opening a Support case with DocuSign developer support here - https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&Channels=7 as there are a lot of variables here to determine what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user id you're using for obtaining the access token. Check it against your login user id. If you're an admin, see the users page in the settings app

### Added

Unfortunately the question is not clear. It could be (see the OP comment) that Pratik is asking why they don't see the application in production. (Production vs demo/developer system.) The reason is that before a client ID (Integration Key / application) is available in production, the [Go Live](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/) procedure must be completed.

Comment: I have docusing account with this mail "RockIT@xyz.co.uk" and I have created developer account using "rockit@xyz.com" I have created integration key in developer account and using that user id but that integration key is not present in this account "RockIT@xyz.co.uk"